# Angular, Detect unsaved changes on navigate away and confirm to leave or stay

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm trying to implement unsaved changes confirm in Angular. I know that I should use CanDeactivate guard, but I don't know how to implement that to be as generic as possible, so I can use it for every components not only one.

I tried to create the following guard, which is worked only with the passed components:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UnsavedChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent> {
  constructor() {}

  canDeactivate(myComponent: MyComponent) {
    return !myComponent.form.dirty;
  }
}
```

Any help please, to convert it to generic guard so I can use it for all the components with forms?

Comment: This is an interesting question i.e. making unsaved change detection generic. You could simply have some form of state (service, NgRx ... dealer's choice) handle whether any component has unsaved changes, and check and reset that state in your guard.

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you please give me more details about your suggestion, and if you don't mind to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can create some interface like DeactivableComponent with method canDeactivate, then you should implement that interface in every component which must support that.
For your guard this is must be like:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UnsavedChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<DeactivableComponent> {
  constructor() {}

  canDeactivate(myComponent: DeactivableComponent ) {
    return myComponent.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to centralise an "unsaved changes" state. You can use state management tools for this (such as NgRx, Ngxs…) or your own system. For example, you could have the following in a service:

```js
private _unsavedChanges = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
get unsavedChanges() {
  return this._unsavedChanges.asObservable();
}

public setUnsavedChanges(changes: boolean) {
  this._unsavedChanges.next(changes);
}
```

With this approach, you call `setUnsavedChanges(true)` every time the user has unsaved changes, and call `setUnsavedChanges(false)` every time the user saves their changes or discards them. In this way, you can use the `unsavedChanges` Observable as the central source of truth as to whether the user can deactivate the route or not.

Of course this means you need to remember to update the state whenever it changes ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a service which keeps track of your page changes.

Add the following to your app component:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
windowBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    if (this.changesService.hasChanges) {
        event.returnValue = "any value here";
    }
}
```

If `event.returnValue` contains any value, the browser will show one of these pop-ups:

[image]

or

[image]

Then to check whether the user selected <kbd>Reload</kbd> or <kbd>Leave</kbd>, the following event will hit:

```
@HostListener('window:unload')
windowOnUnload() {
    //User pressed Reload/Leave.
}
```